# Using SAPUI5 to create Master XML View

Tags: xml, sapui5

I currently have an html page where I am attempting to determine if the user is one a mobile device or not.  If they are not on a mobile device I want to load a "master" XML view to build future views off.  Currently this is being accomplished for the mobile device through sapm.m.App({initialPage:"masterMobile"})

The closest online example I have found is: http://scn.sap.com/people/konstantin.anikeev/blog/2013/02#jive_content_id_appView

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're actually asking how to tell on what sort of device your UI5 app is running. There's the device API which is documented at

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.Device.system.html

but you also may want to consider implementing the "device model" pattern which is described in many places, one of them here:

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/325b8edafcfa4c9c8fbd42455a60e379.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

It I was overthinking it.  The solution was to use

```
sapu.ui.view({"javascriptController", viewName:"XMLMasterView", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML{);
```

This set the parent XML view which would be inherited from all "children views"